# my command changes color as soon as i type the string

Tags: python

I am  beginner. so after typing a print command followed by the parenthesis, as soon as I type the string the command color changes from blue to yellow. After I try to run the command SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier keeps appearing.

the command 'print' was supposed to remain blue, while the parenthesis white and the string red.

Comment: What's the context here? Are you talking about an IDE? Or maybe a specific REPL?

Comment: You should at least show exactly what it is you're typing in, a [mcve] of the syntax error causing code

Comment: Please post the [full error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341) along with the other details Barmar and Sayse requested. You can [edit] your question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.